# Need some way to easily clear all ignored/favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags, tag-watching

I've just found a way to add many tags to ignored/favorite (sorry, it's called *watched* now, but I will call it on ol' manner) list by just select all text on the page <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and pasting it to the corresponding list:

> [image: too much tags]

But it seems there is no way to clear all tags on ignored/favorite list without affecting paired list. And now my suggestion is to add something to clear these lists separately.

It's too tedious to remove tags from list by one ... and one ... and one...

Comment: Does doing it in your profile page (under tag watching and ignoring) helps ? there's a cross in front of each tag and the list is a little larger to handle.

Comment: @Tensibai Yep, this helps a little. At least there is no need to move mouse pointer, just click many times on the cross :)

Comment: For now you could try running `$('.delete-tag').click()` in your console when in edit mode to get rid of them all